# How can I show lambda functions on backtraces?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda, backtrace

I'm writing a `C++11` software and I'm using lambdas. When I print the backtrace with `backtrace_symbols_fd` all functions are demangled except of lambda. It's a bit obvious because they are anonymous functions, but there is a way to get more insight instead of a raw pointer?

I'm using GCC 4.8 on Linux

Comment: It's probably useful to mention in which context (debugger? toolchain?) you want to see this.

Comment: Yes, what compiler and debugger are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of useful information does exist in the binary, because GDB is able to show more useful names for lambda functions e.g.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  <lambda()>::operator()(void) const (__closure=0x7fffffffd5ef) at ll.cc:3
#1  0x00000000004005e7 in main () at ll.cc:3
```

(ALthough maybe the debug info just says it's a closure type, as GDB shows all such functions as `<lambda()>::operator()`)

The mangled name of a template instantiated with a closure type includes a unique name e.g.

```
#3  0x0000000000400712 in func<main()::<lambda()> >(<lambda()>) (t=...) at l.cc:4
```

but maybe the name is only used when it's needed in other mangled names.

With GCC you can also print out the name of the closure's `operator()` by printing the pre-defined variable `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, which shows something like `main()::<lambda()>`

Using GDB's Python API I can get yet another name for the same closure, e.g.

```
(gdb) python import gdb; print gdb.block_for_pc(0x8048591).function.name
__lambda0::operator()() const
```

So that's at least three different names! So I think it's maybe a limitation of `backtrace_symbols_fd` that it can't find names for the lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard:

§5.1.2/3 states:

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the
>   closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type.

I don't think there is a way to get more useful information. Basically, lambdas are just instances of anonymous classes.

Comment: They still need some kind of name, for linkage and name mangling purposes, even if that name cannot be spoken by users. e.g. if you instantiate a template with a closure type the compiler needs to encode the closure type in the mangled name of the template specialization.